# TFS failing gated checkin when merging back to trunk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

Having a problem with TFS and TFS CI in the following scenario (I have simplified it though it is essentially the same problem):

1. I have a trunk (set of csprojs in one VS solution)
2. I have a branch (taken from the trunk)
   -- in this branch I have created a new file, say "MyRepository.cs"
3. I merged my branch back into the trunk
   -- all seems well... (in pending changes the file is marked as "merge, branch")
4. I checkin my merged pending changes to trunk
5. This kicks off a gated checkin in TFS
6. This fails and I get a message from TFS CI:

"CSC: Source file 'Repositories\MyRepository.cs' could not be found"

"TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'."

When I checked in the MyRepository.cs file I obviously checked in the csproj file for the assembly that MyRepository.cs is contained in.  This csproj has the line to include the new cs file, i.e.:

```
<Compile Include="Repositories\MyRepository.cs" />
```

So the problem is I dont understand why TFS is complaining that the .cs file is not there even though I am checking it in and it is included in the csproj file.

I'm suspecting that the fact that I did a merge from a branch back to trunk is causing the problem but I cant tell why.  I am relatively new to TFS CI so any pointers of where to look now would be a great help.

**UPDATE** - have since discovered that the working directory for the source files that TFS CI uses is not pulling the MyRepository.cs file into it and is not pulling the latest (checkin set) version of the .csproj file (looks like its the old trunk version still).  This seems very bizarre as error message (above) insinuates that its getting the .csproj but is not getting the MyRepository.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was occuring because the account that the TFS build agent used did not have retrieve permissions on the branch (or any other permissions).  So the files that I had updated and the new files that were merged from branch into trunk were not appearing in the trunk build.  A little annoying that TFS did not complain about this explicitly and instead just went a head and used the old trunk files (or if it did complain I could not find it in the logs).

Summary: Giving the build agent account permissions on the branch fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error indicates that the csproj file does indeed have your change in it, because the compile is looking for the file. However, it also indicates that the actual cs file is either not part of the check in, or it is checked in to a spot different than where the csproj file is expecting it. One other possible solution (if you have verified the other two) is that somehow your builds workspace doesn't have a mapping that would include the Repositories folder.

Comment: The .cs file is definitely part of the checkin.  Its folder location (in pending changes) is correct as well.  Though I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "builds workspace" ;), I already have existing files in the Repositories folder and they arent causing a problem (havent before) - so I dont think it is the folder location.

Comment: In the Build Definition there is a tab for mapping the workspace, that is how the build knows which files to pull down. A way to diagnose it would be to create a shelf set out of your pending changes. Delete all of the files on your workstation, and do a Get Specific Version with both of the overwrite checkbox's checked. After that completes, get your shelf set back and see how ti compiles locally then. I've never seen this failure, you have to have something incorrect and this will help you figure it out.